# Powershell calculated value in where-object clause

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to make my Powershell script as simple as possible. But I'm having trouble with the where-object clause. The following code does what I want:

```
# define calculated variables 
$mytime = @{label="Time";expression={$_.timegenerated}}
$myeid  = @{l="EID";e={$_.instanceid -band 0xffff}}
$mymsg  = @{l="Msg 1st 20";e={$_.message.substring(0,20)}}

# get data
Get-Eventlog system |
  where-object { ( $_.instanceid -band 0xffff ) -eq 6005} |
  select-object -first 10 instanceid,
    $mytime,
    $myeid,
    $mymsg
```

But I was thinking it would be more simple if the where-object could use the $myeid

```
...
  where-object { $myeid -eq 6005} |
...
```

But I don't get any results when I use this where-object clause. I've tried various combinations of wrapping it in braces, parentheses, and $(...) with no luck. What am I missing?

And later, I found there was already a script property to extract the EventID, but I'm still wondering why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$myeid is just a hashtable with a string and a scriptblock.  Select-object is programmed to make use of it.  Somehow you'd have to run the scriptblock $myeid.e to get a value out of it.  This comes close to your original code.  Without the parentheses, "-eq 6005" gets ignored.  I added 0xf0000 to 6005.

```
$myeid  = @{l="EID";e={$_.instanceid -band 0xffff}}
@{instanceid=989045} | where-object { (& $myeid.e) -eq 6005}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
instanceid                     989045
```

Comment: `(.$myeid.e) -eq 6005`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That's true, without the parentheses it ignores "-eq 6005".  The "&" and "." seem to work just as well.

Comment: `.` will execute in the local scope, mimicking the behavior of `Where-Object` :)